# PL/SQL returning contents of a table

Tags: sql, .net, oracle, weblogic

Currently working on a .Net application for viewing the contents of a table, I faced difficulties with the function that returns the contents of the table.

I use the Oracle WebLogic Server to interface comics and application, I have a function that returns a desired record of the table but I unable to adapt to it returns all records of table.

I used tables, objects I have not been able to operate the pipeline.
Here is the function that returns a record.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE DMD_REC AS OBJECT
(
matricule VARCHAR2(10),
nom VARCHAR2(15),
prenom VARCHAR2(15),
adresse VARCHAR2(10),
profile VARCHAR2(15),
service  VARCHAR2(15),
date_dmd DATE
);
```

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION aff_dmd 
(dmd_mat IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN DMD_REC IS
dmd_found demande%rowtype;
dmd_rtn DMD_REC;
BEGIN
SELECT *
INTO dmd_found
FROM demande
WHERE demande.matricule=dmd_mat;
dmd_rtn := DMD_REC
(
dmd_found.matricule, 
dmd_found.nom, 
dmd_found.prenom, 
dmd_found.adresse, 
dmd_found.profile, 
dmd_found.service, 
dmd_found.date_dmd
);
RETURN dmd_rtn;
END aff_dmd;
```

Sorry for my english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function returns an object which fits one row.  You need it to return a table of such objects.

So first you need a table type:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE DMD_NT AS TABLE OF DMD_REC;
```

Then you have to convert your function to use this new type.  In the absence of any other requirements this revision will select all records in the `demande` table when a NULL is passed:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION aff_dmd 
    (dmd_mat IN VARCHAR2 := null)
    RETURN DMD_NT 
IS
    dmd_rtn DMD_NT;
BEGIN
    SELECT DMD_REC
        (
        d.matricule, 
        d.nom, 
        d.prenom, 
        d.adresse, 
        d.profile, 
        d.service, 
        d.date_dmd
        )
    BULK COLLECT INTO dmd_rtn
    FROM demande
    WHERE 
        ( dmd_mat is null
          or d.matricule = dmd_mat
        );
    RETURN dmd_rtn;
END aff_dmd;
/
```

The BULK COLLECT populates a collection which is stored in *session* memory.  If your table is large (say more than 5000) this may create problems with memory resources.  In which case you should consider creating a pipelined function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION aff_dmd 
    (dmd_mat IN VARCHAR2 := null)
  RETURN DMD_NT PIPELINED
IS
    dmd_rtn DMD_NT;
BEGIN
    loop
        SELECT DMD_REC
            (
            d.matricule, 
            d.nom, 
            d.prenom, 
            d.adresse, 
            d.profile, 
            d.service, 
            d.date_dmd
            )
        BULK COLLECT INTO dmd_rtn limit 1000
        FROM demande
        WHERE 
            ( dmd_mat is null
              or d.matricule = dmd_mat
            );
        exit when dmd_rtn.count() = 0;
        for idx in 1..dmd_rtn.count() loop
            pipe row (dmd_rtn(idx));
        end loop;
    end loop
    RETURN;
END aff_dmd;
```

Pipelined functions have an overhead.  You should consider whether there is a way you can make it work with SYS_REFCURSOR as @BobJarvis suggested.